# Js reload files (delete file cache) in folder

Tags: javascript

I have app where I create, edit and do other manipulations with pdf files. 
And I have problem: when I edit pdf and save it, then open pdf file there is old version for this file and I need do Ctrl+F5 to reload file,after that all is ok. Maybe there is a way to delete old file cache using js or php?

Comment: 100% sure no one will understand this

Comment: Think this is simple question. I have  pdf file. Than I edit this pdf and need do ctrl+f5 to delete cache manually. My  question is - how to it using code?

Answer (score 0):

While serving pdf back from server you need to send cache expiry header as back dated to make the browser not cache the pdf file.